# Proof in Rudin. Denseness of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, rational-numbers

There is a point in Rudin's proof where he says that by the Archemedean property, there exists $m_1, m_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$nx <m_1$$ and $$-nx<m_2$$ and therefore $$-m_2 <nx <m_1.$$No issues there.

Then he makes the claim that then there exists an $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ (with $m_2\leq m \leq m_1$) such that $$m-1 \leq nx <m,$$ virtually saying that $nx$ lives between two consecutive integers. Now this is certainly $intuitively$ true (and perhaps so intuitively true that Rudin didn't feel as though he had to prove it), but I was wondering how to $prove$ it? I couldn't think of anything that stayed away from saying things like "obviously" or "goes without saying".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply uses that any subset of $\mathbf Z$  which is bounded from below (and in particular, any finite subset) is well-ordered, like $\mathbf N$, i.e. has a least element.

SSo here, thet of $m\in\mathbf Z$ such that $nx< m$ is bounded from below by the integer $m_2$, so there is a least such $m$, which by definition means that $m-1\le nx$.

Comment: Love it thank you. I'm assuming you mean 'the set of $m$'.

Comment: Do you have a quick and easy proof that any subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ that is bounded from below is well-ordered?

Comment: @Luuuuuke . If $r\in \Bbb R$ is a lower bound for $S\subset \Bbb Z,$ there exists $z_0\in \Bbb Z$ with $z_0<r.$ The function $f(z)=z-z_0$ is an order-isomorphism from $\{z\in \Bbb Z: z>z_0\}$ to $\Bbb N.$ [...Obviously $f$ strictly preserves order, and by induction on $n\in \Bbb N,$ every $n\in \Bbb N$ is in the image of $f$...] So if $S$ is not empty then $\{f(z):z\in S\}$ has a least element $n\in \Bbb N$ so $f^{-1}(n)=\min S.$

Comment: Yes: if $m\in\mathbf ZE$ is a lower bound for $S$, you have an order-preserving bijection from the  set $\{m,m+1,m+2,\dots\}$ to $\mathbf N$, defined by $n\mapsto n-m$, and $\mathbf N$ is well-ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m_0=\max\{m\in\mathbb Z:\ m\leq nx\}$. If $m_0+1\leq nx$, then we would contradict the maximality of $m_0$, so $m_0+1>nx$. Thus
$$
m_0\leq nx< m_0+1. 
$$
If you want to be really careful, you need to prove that on any bounded set of integers, the supremum is a maximum.